# Getting varaibles from objects of different types inside an object array

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2013, object-type

So I got this small problem on getting variables from certain classes that are in a primitive multidimensional object array.

Simple explanation:

I got a primitive multidimensional object array which I'm using as a level grid. This array is filled with different types of objects to create a level (wall object, obstacle object etc.), so that's why I choose to use the "object" type..

Now all these types of objects have all three variables in common: an int xpos variable, an int ypos variable and a SolidBrush br variable.

What I'm using now is different Lists of the corresponding object type to get their positions and color for drawing. Now this is extra code of space which I don't actually need because every object is already in the main multidimensional array.

So how does one loop through a object array to get variables from different types of object classes that are inside this object array. Is it even possible as I'm using a global "object" type for my array?

It's a really simple question but I can't find an answer as I don't really know how to type the right keywords for the search. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: So I got it working thanks to using an Interface. Thanks everybody for your help and input. I would like to mark every interface answer but I can't so I'll mark the first comment. Sorry guys. Thank you all!

Comment: TL;DR You should add code samples instead of a long explanation! :D

Comment: I didn't think I'd need to use code as it's a very simple (straight forward?) question.

Comment: @GhunerStrudel Then make your question *simpler* to read, if the issue is too simple!!

Comment: @GhunterStrudel A picture is worth a 1000 words, and a good [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem is worth a 1000 pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an interface with three properties: xpos, ypos, and brush. Have all your existing types that you put in the array implement this interface. Then change your multidimensional array type from Object to the new interface.

Comment: This sounds promising. I'll try that. Thanks mate!

Comment: It works. I gave your comment the mark as it was the first comment with the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Create an interface and an array of objects that implement that interface:

```
// choose a better name and make the properties read-only (get;} if necessary
public interface ILevelItem  
{
    public int XPos {get; set;}
    public int YPos {get; set;}
    public SolidBrush Brush {get; set;}
}

public class Wall : ILevelItem
{
    ....
}

public class Obstacle : ILevelItem
{
    ....
}
```

Now your "level grid" can be an array of the items

```
public ILevelItem[,] levelGrid;
```

and you can access the properties without casting:

```
int x = levelGrid[0,0].XPos;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should decorate your different objects with interfaces, i.e. `IObstacle`, `IWall`, `IMonster`, `ITreasure`... then you can easily test if `objetsOfWorld[i]` is an obstacle, or a wall.

Then you can access the needed property (x, y, brush).

If theses properties are shared by all objects, you may have a parent interface, `IObjectOfMyWorld` that exposes the 3 properties. Then your array will be an array of `IObjectOfMyWorld`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't use "object" here, because it's the type of every object you create in your application. You should create an **abstract class** with all these properties (xpos etc.) or an **interface**. All other classes which uses these properties should then implement this interface or extend the abstract class.

```
abstract class YourAbstractClass
{
    public int XPos { get; set; } 
}

class WallObject : YourAbstractClass
{

}
```

Then you can have one `List<YourAbstractClass>` with all your objects.

You should search for the keyword [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173149(v=vs.80).aspx) ;)

Comment: I will remember that keyword. Thanks for the advice.